# android - animating a shape

Tags: java, android, graphics

After creating a shape i don't know how to set up an animation. The circle I create is in the center of the screen and should move to the right margin. Can someone explain how to animate it?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
    Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bg);  
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, (float) (canvas.getHeight()/1.8), 13, paint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple view animation by creating an xml with animation requirements. Apply the animation on OnViewCreated() method to the required object.

Check view animation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Example: if you want to animate nfcTerminal object, then just create *nfc_terminal_bounce.xml* with translate and alpha properties.

Sample code:

**nfcTerminal.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),  R.anim.nfc_terminal_bounce));**

Comment: And how do i get my 'canvas circle' into a xml file?